# Vercel not picking up changes made in site-packages

Tags: python, ubuntu, flask, vercel

Changes were made in a cypher.py file, which is part of pytube. The changes I made do not reflect when I try to deploy my application to vercel as it uses the requirements.txt file. I need it to use the changed cypher.py file.

**Problem Explaination**

- I have been trying to download a youtube videos audio, so I used pytube.
- Pytube needs changes in the cypher.py file to run, which is located in the site-packages folder.
- Making these changes allows me to run the code on localhost.
- When using vercel to deploy, it uses the requirments.txt to download pytube, which does not have the changed cypher.py file
- This results in an error

**Vercel Error Logs**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/flask/app.py", line 2190, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/var/task/flask/app.py", line 1486, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/var/task/flask/app.py", line 1484, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/var/task/flask/app.py", line 1469, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)
  File "./app.py", line 23, in home
    audioFile = download_audio(videoUrl)
  File "./app.py", line 9, in download_audio
    audio = yt.streams.filter(only_audio=True).first()
  File "/var/task/pytube/__main__.py", line 296, in streams
    return StreamQuery(self.fmt_streams)
  File "/var/task/pytube/__main__.py", line 188, in fmt_streams
    extract.apply_signature(stream_manifest, self.vid_info, self.js)
  File "/var/task/pytube/extract.py", line 409, in apply_signature
    cipher = Cipher(js=js)
  File "/var/task/pytube/cipher.py", line 43, in __init__
    self.throttling_plan = get_throttling_plan(js)
  File "/var/task/pytube/cipher.py", line 405, in get_throttling_plan
    raw_code = get_throttling_function_code(js)
  File "/var/task/pytube/cipher.py", line 311, in get_throttling_function_code
    name = re.escape(get_throttling_function_name(js))
  File "/var/task/pytube/cipher.py", line 296, in get_throttling_function_name
    raise RegexMatchError(
pytube.exceptions.RegexMatchError: get_throttling_function_name: could not find match for multiple
```

Note that adding the following lines to the cypher.py file under function_patterns() will fix the above error

```
r'a\.[a-zA-Z]\s*&&\s*\([a-z]\s*=\s*a\.get\("n"\)\)\s*&&\s*'
r'\([a-z]\s*=\s*([a-zA-Z0-9$]{2,3})(\[\d+\])?\([a-z]\)'
```

**Flask application code:**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, send_file
from pytube import YouTube
import os

app = Flask(__name__)

def download_audio(videoUrl):
    yt = YouTube(videoUrl)
    audio = yt.streams.filter(only_audio=True).first()
    outFile = audio.download(output_path="audioConverted")
    print(outFile)
    base, ext = os.path.splitext(outFile)
    newFile = base + '.mp3'
    os.rename(outFile, newFile)
    return newFile

audioFolderPath = "audioConverted"

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        videoUrl = request.form.get("youtubeurl")
        audioFile = download_audio(videoUrl)
        if audioFile:
            filename = os.path.basename(audioFile)
            return send_file(audioFile, as_attachment=True, mimetype='audio/mpeg', download_name=filename)
    return render_template("index.html")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I use Ubuntu 20.04 LTS